# Why loadImage is not called in p5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am new with [p5js](https://p5js.org). I am trying to load an image using loadImage().

This is my code:

```js
function setup (img) {
  classifier.classify(img, gotResult)
  appendGif(img)
}


/* This code return a random tag to use in the
  url.
  variable tag make reference to an array I wouldn't show here.
*/
function getRandomTag () {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * tags.length)

  return tags[randomIndex]
}

/* This function return a random gif from giphy api */
async function getRandomGif (randomTag) {
  const url = `${baseURL}${gifs}${random}?api_key=${api_key}&rating=${rating}&tag=${randomTag}`
  const randomResponse = await fetch(url)
  const responseJSON = await randomResponse.json()
  const gif = responseJSON.data.image_url

  return gif
}

/* And then, this code append the random gif to an img element in my html*/
function appendGif (gif) {
  const imgElement = document.createElement('img')
  imgElement.src = gif
  kebabElement.appendChild(imgElement)
}

/* I am using the preload function as p5js docs say
 and I load the image with loadImage function */
function preload(gif) {
  classifier = ml5.imageClassifier('MobileNet');
  const img = loadImage(gif)
  return img
}



function gotResult (error, result) {
 if (error) throw error
 console.info(result)
}

async function main () {
  const randomTag = getRandomTag()
  const gif = await getRandomGif(randomTag)
  const img = await preload(gif)
  return setup(img)
}

main();
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="gif, gifs, giphy" />
    <meta name="description" content="An initial gif is presented on the page. Click the gif to retrieve other somewhat related gif based on AI recognition of the initial image." />
    <meta name="author" content="Diesan Romero" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <a href="#" class="brand-logo">GIF KEBAB</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
      <div id="kebab"></div>
    </main>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js" integrity="sha512-gQVBYBvfC+uyor5Teonjr9nmY1bN+DlOCezkhzg4ShpC5q81ogvFsr5IV4xXAj6HEtG7M1Pb2JCha97tVFItYQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@latest/dist/ml5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/index.js" type="module" ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but I am getting this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: loadImage is not defined

What I want to do here is load that auto generated gif with the loadImage() function.
In short, I am getting an error when calling the loadImage() function. How is possible to be not defined if I am loading p5js on my html?

Comment: I think this might have something to do with the fact that you're passing inputs to `setup()` and `preload()`. I've never seen `setup(img)` or anything like that, the parentheses are always empty.

Comment: As @jstl suggests, you should create your own functions with parameters and call them where you want! For example, create your own `function setupImage(img){...}` and call it inside setup like: `function setup(){ setupImage(img); }`

Comment: preload is a parameter-less function that is automatically being called by p5 just before setup, which is also parameter-less. On top, both functions don't return promises, so both cannot be awaited.

Answer (score -2):

Split the gif into frames
Then ....loadImage("gif1", "gif2" ......) and so on in the correct order.